# MVC5 - OWIN - IAuthenticationManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap, owin

I am using structuremap.mvc5 although this question would apply equally to any DI container.  I need to configure the container such that it can create a controller that takes Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager.  I am configuring the container via a PreApplicationStartMethod.  Is an instance of Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager available at this time, or is there something I can use as a delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
_.For<IAuthenticationManager>().UseSpecial(expression =>
    expression.ConstructedBy( i => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

Comment: For anyone who found this question when using Unity as your DI container that code is as follows: container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

Comment: I still don't understand how this is an acceptable answer. I want to tell Unity (or my DI container) how and when to create an instance of an IAuthenticationManager. I still don't know a concrete example of such an interface or how to avoid using the magic 'GetOwinContext' which seems like a poor mans DI. Any pointers anyone?